# Need to delete unreferenced rows from a Drupal MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, drupal, sql-delete

I am running a PHP MySQL command script (cleanup.php) via cron that deletes the duplicate and BS content from the aggregator_item table (Table 2 below). The problem is that over time the aggregator_category_item table (Table 1 below) contains too many unreferenced rows.

Ideally, Table 1 and Table 2 should have the **same** number of rows.

I need a MySQL command, mysql_query(), that would delete all the rows in the aggregator_category_item table (Table 1) for the following condition:

If the **idd** number in aggregator_category_item table (Table 1) is **NOT** found within the aggregator_item table (Table 2), then delete these unreferenced rows from the aggregator_category_item table (Table 1). I would like to add this MySQL delete command to my current MySQL command cron script.

Below are the following two tables in the Drupal Database:

```
Table 1: aggregator_category_item (145,000 rows)
-----------------------------------------------
iid        cid
6644403    2


Table 2: aggregator_item (8700 rows)
------------------------------------
iid      fid  title  link       author  description  timestamp
6644403  25   hello  http://...         hello there  1348243145
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
delete from aggregator_category_item
where iid not in (select iid from aggregator_item)
```

Comment: would this be the command I use:
    mysql_query("delete from `singlein_drpl1`. `aggregator_category_item` WHERE iid not in (select iid from aggregator_item)");

Comment: Thank you. How would I write the command to be placed in a php file (cleanup.php). The database name is singlein_drpl1

Comment: @Sammy That would be best asked as a new question.

Comment: It would probably be wise to run this with SELECT instead of DELETE first, to make absolutely sure it will only delete the rows you want.